# Eclipse hangs when creating project on Ubuntu (Vbox)

Tags: virtualbox, java, eclipse

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on Virtual Box. It's the 64 bit version, and I have allocated 1024 mb of ram.

My problem is when creating a new Java Project in eclipse, it just hangs and takes forever. I have never seen it finish creating a project. Usually I have to shut down the machine. When I restart it, I see the folder for the project I was trying to create in the workspace. When I tried to delete it in eclipse, it just hanged again.

I read somewhere that its not hanging, and that its fetching some stuff. Does anyone know what might be wrong? I really want to get it Eclipse running on ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have a swap partition set up?

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how I can do it? @NickWeinberg